# Receive from Transaction Msmq Queue Windows Server c#

Tags: c#, transactions, msmq

I try to receive a message from a message queue, which was created in a transaction queue on Windows Server 2012 R2.

What I do in code is the following

```
MessageQueueTransaction trans = new MessageQueueTransaction();
trans.Begin();
Message envelope;
envelope = mq.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), trans);
```

The last line throws a `MessageQueueException` with the [MessageQueueErrorCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.messaging.messagequeueerrorcode(v=vs.110).aspx) `TransactionSequence`.

When I run the exact same code against a transactional MsMq on my Windows 7 machine, the code works fine.

So I guess that on Windows Server 2012 R2 MsMq works differently.

I must add that our software runs multiple threads receiving messages from a queue.

Comment: Did you find any solution since then?